# how to get url data from embedly and save it into database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, embed

i am using jquery embedly plugin to embed video . but the problem is that i want to save the video information such as title,description, thumbnail etc into database . i know for that we can use ajax , but the problem is i am not able to find a solution for getting data of url . have read embedly api also but it tells how to embed the url , but i need the url data . can anyone help me providing some more information .

like we include the file jquery.embedly.js

and then use the  code

```
           $(document).ready(function() {
$("#embedform").bind('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var q = $(this).find('.url').val();
    if (q == '')
        return false;

    $.embedly(q, {maxWidth: 410, wrapElement: 'div', key : '4d1f889c20ed11e1abb14040d3dc5c07'}, function(oembed, dict){
        console.log('hi');
        if (oembed == null)
            $("#embed").html('<p class="text"> Not A Valid URL </p>');
        else 
            $("#embed").html(oembed.code);
    });
});
```

});

but this helps in embedding the url how to get the data such as title, description, thumbnail etc ?